# What does "has no sort of time with" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In [Greenmantle](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/559/pg559-images.html#chap09), by John Buchan, an American government official was on a secret mission in Turkey during First World War, and he discovered the Muslims are waiting for a new prophet, called Greenmantle, who should be aided by one woman called Hilda von Einem. Now his British friend is asking him whether he knew anything about Greenmantle:

> “Why, no, but I have reached one conclusion. I opine that the hapless prophet **has no sort of time with** that lady. I opine that he will soon wish himself in Paradise. For if Almighty God ever created a female devil it’s Madame von Einem.”

What does this mean?

Comment: As a native English speaker from the UK, I don't recognise the phrase at all. A Google search finds no instances of "have/has no sort of time with" other than this one. (The nearest phrase I'm familiar with is "to have no time for someone" which means to find someone annoying or tiresome, to disapprove of them. But from context, that is clearly not the meaning here.)

Comment: @JamesMartin: *The prophet **has no time for her*** (wouldn't "waste" even a moment of his time interacting with her) looks like *exactly* the intended sense. Reading the text as a *current idiomatic usage* would have us understand it as *he didn't have **any** "kind of time" with her* - (and he *certainly* didn't have a ***good*** time with her). But that doesn't really work, semantically.

Comment: Presumably he means that the prophet's association with Hilda von Einem will not be at all pleasant.

Comment: Ahmed - Google Books reports several dozen matches for the sequence ***no sort of time with***. But upon examination, it turns out *every single one of them* is for this exact source. *Whatever* you or anyone else think it means, I advise you not to copy it!

Comment: And don't say "I opine" either, which sounds formal and dated. *In my opinion, the unfortunate prophet should not spend any time with that lady.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Indeed I was not suggesting the current idiomatic usage. From context, Weather Vane and Kate Bunting's interpretation that he *should* not waste any time with her sound more plausible than the interpretation that he *would* not waste any time with her.

Comment: @JamesMartin: That interpretation doesn't really work for me, because it seems to turn on the writers *first* use of ***I opine*** having the meaning ***I recommend***. But then it makes no sense for the second use of the same verb to mean ***I recommend** that he will soon wish himself in Paradise.* The reality is that in both cases, ***I opine*** is just an "affected" alternative to ***I think*** (that something is "the current situation"; it's not about recommending a *different* state of affairs or course of action).

Comment: @FumbleFingers We are spending too long on this. But it's perfectly plausible to say: I think he should not get involved with that lady, and I think that he will come to realise that himself. In particular, the point is that he will "wish himself in Paradise" *because* of his involvement with her. If you read the first phrase as meaning that he *won't* tangle with her, then what is it that will lead to him wishing himself dead?

Comment: @JamesMartin - Paradise is, canonically, a _good_ place.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Agreed! So what do you think the phrase "he will soon wish himself in Paradise" means? Other ideas welcome, but I think it has to mean: the prophet will soon wish that his earthly life is over, that he is up in heaven instead of down on earth. (And in context, the reason that he will soon wish for an end to his earthly life is the grief he's getting from his involvement with the "demon" Mme von Einen.)

Comment: @JamesMartin - I believe you have it totally right. It is jocular, of course. The American does not really think the 'prophet' is contemplating suicide. Maybe worth noting that Buchan was Scottish (from Perth) and I cannot discount the idea that 'has no sort of time' might be something they said around there at the time or in his youth. Or what Buchan, in 1916, imagined Americans might say.

Comment: @JamesMartin - I remember the philosopher Bertrand Russell (famously atheist) wrote that he had once asked a nun what she supposed would happen to her after she died. She replied (he wrote) 'I believe I shall have eternal bliss, but please don't talk about such unpleasant things'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: I think we *can* reasonably discount the idea that 'has no sort of time' might be something they said around there at the time or in his youth. Per my second comment above, *every single one* of the dozens of instances of ***no sort of time with*** in Google Books is for this one source. If the usage ever had any meaningful level of currency (such that Buchan could reasonably expect many of his readers to *recognize* as opposed to "decode, interpret" the expression), we'd surely find other matches. It's a quirky one-off, imho.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - widening the search suggests that 'no time with' could be a not very frequent variant of 'no time for'  _I have no time with people who are constantly rude to other people without any good reason_,  and I can see 'no sort of' as an intensifier of that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Sure - Buchan didn't invent his usage out of thin air. But his *exact* version (which is, after all, what's being queried here) obviously never had any significant currency, and it would be wrong to give learners the impression that it is (or even *was*) a perfectly valid stylistic choice. It's easily understood, but it's still a weird one-off.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a common phrase. FF notes in a comment:

> Google Books reports several dozen matches for the sequence *no sort of time with*. But upon examination, it turns out every single one of them is for this exact source.

It is possible that instead of "time" the author meant "truck" (from [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/truck)):

> : close association or connection
> | will have no *truck* with crooks

Greenmantle is a prophet (presumably of God), while von Einem is described as "a female devil", so it would make sense that he'd have no truck with her.